# New window url not found in tomcat server of react production build

Tags: reactjs, tomcat9

I am new in react. My project working fine in development state (localhost) but in production build (tomcat 9 web server) does not. When I click on tree node it opens a new window but show page not found. My sample code is bellow.

**app.js**

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router basename={"/sbfrontapp"}>    
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={SBLogIn} />
          <Route exact path="/sb-login-interface" component={SBLogIn} />
          <Route exact path="/sb-user-interface" component={SBLayout} />
          <Route exact path="/sb-user-component" component={CommonCompLoader} />
        </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

**treeView.js**

```
class TreeView extends PureComponent {

 onNodeClick = (node) => {
    if (node.isLeaf) {
      const cmdText = node.value.split("_")[1].toUpperCase();
      if (cmdText !== null && cmdText !== "") {
        
       let browser = window.self;
       let opts = "width=900,height=600,toolbar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,resizable =no";
        browser.open("/sb-user-component", "new-tab", opts, true);

      }
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { expanded, nodeData, loading } = this.state;

    return loading ? (
      <LoadImg />
    ) : (
      <CheckboxTree
        expanded={expanded}
        iconsClass="fa5"
        nodes={nodeData}
        onClick={this.onNodeClick}        
        onExpand={this.onExpand}
        expandOnClick="true"
      />
    );
  }

}
```

Thanks in advance.